# How to correctly produce and consume UTF-8 json in Python3? (with flask and requests)

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, utf-8

I've made some basic code to explain my question:

produceUTF8.py (replies 'ít wórked!' with unicode characters) - you run this first

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from sys import argv

from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False # contribution from Erdem

@app.route('/reply', methods=['POST'])
def reply():
    """Fetch a reply
    """
    print("DEBUG entered")
    params = request.json
    print("DEBUG entered2")
    if not params:
        return jsonify({
            'status': 'error',
            'error': 'Request must be of the application/json type!',
        })

    reply = "ít wórked!"

    # Send the response.
    return jsonify({
        'status': 'ok',
        'reply': reply,
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

consumeUTF8.py (posts the message 'óíá' to get answer from producer)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',}
DATA = '{"message": "óíá"}'
my_request = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/reply', headers=HEADERS, data=DATA)
response = my_request.json()['reply']
```

In my producer I am getting "Bad Request (400)" and in the consumer "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)."

It seems to be a problem in `params = request.json` as seen in the debug prints. What is the recommended approach here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the way you make the request by encoding the `data` object :

```
my_request = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/reply', 
                           headers=HEADERS, 
                           data=DATA.encode('utf-8'))

#>>> ít wórked with óíá!
```

---

If you add a try/except statement in the app, it returns :

```
try:
    params = request.json
except Exception as e:
    params = None
    print(e)
```

> 400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 14: invalid continuation byte

You could use this pattern to assign a default value for `param`

Comment: It stopped the Bad Requests! Thanks.. I will create an issue on Postman snippet generator to add this encode part =)

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried the code but may be setting

```
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
```

may help.

Comment: Now it works on Postman the response in UTF-8, but it is still getting Bad Request (400) from the consumeUTF8.py. I edited the code with your contribution, thanks! What is even more crazy is that I generate snippets from Postman using request and http.client and they also get the same error!